# Connecting to Docker SQL Server from another PC

Tags: sql-server, docker, lan

I cannot find the way to connect to my Docker Microsoft SQL Server through Management Studio if I am on another PC which is on the same internet (LAN).

And I ping my other PC and use RDP to connect to it, so that I think should not be the part of a problem we are looking for....or?

**OS:** Windows 11

**Docker** version: 24.0.5, build ced0996 (desktop version)

This is the command I'm using:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=MyPass" -p 1433:1433 
       --name sqlserver2022 -v  data2022:/var/opt/mssql 
       --restart unless-stopped -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

I tried:

- Turned off firewall on both PCs
- Have the turned on settings: Enabled TCP/IP in Server Network Configuration
- Have allowed remote connections to my SQL Server

And if it's possible to succeed, can I connect only specified IP without port?

Comment: Try to update the question with: the docker version, the docker host os, the docker SQL server image version, the docker run command, and what you have entered on the SSMS to connect to the sql server.

Comment: ip address... ip address with lets say: 
192.168.178.42;
192.168.178.42, 1433;

Comment: How do you try to connect? What error do you get?

Comment: can you connect to your docker sql server from the pc on which docker is running on?

Comment: Have you checked the Docker container's log to ensure that it contains no errors (i.e.: is it actually running)? One thing I'll note is that the `SA_PASSWORD` environment variable has been deprecated for quite a while now, it should be using `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` instead. Ref: [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server).

Comment: If your Docker host's IP address is `192.168.178.42` then from the host itself, or from the other PC you're connecting from, can you execute `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.178.42 -Port 1433` in a PowerShell prompt and connect successfully? If this cannot connect then SSMS will not be able to either.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning here is log file, and i tried to use mssql_sa_password and its still the same.. and testing netconnection fails... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Je_EeC99VtQdtvH_qRwngrvNfaOxpz6/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: on SSMS try with: **sqlserver2022, 1433** and the username and password with sa e relative password. Double-check that there isn't an SQL server running on your host on the same port.